# Using a docker container for testing in Atlassian Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: docker, amazon-dynamodb, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm using a dynamodb docker container to run some tests in an Atlassian Bitbucket pipeline. These steps work locally with the same exact `docker run` command, but for some reason I cannot connect to the db container after it starts while running in the pipeline:

```
image: python:3.6

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - docker
        script:
          - docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --name dynamodb --entrypoint java amazon/dynamodb-local -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -inMemory
          - curl http://localhost:8000
        services:
          - docker
```

The curl command returns:

```
curl http://localhost:8000 % Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed
Time Time Time Current Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:-
-:-- 0curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I've tried with both localhost and dynamodb as the host names with the same result. I've also posted this on the Atlassian Community, but got no answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not start `amazon/dynamodb-local` manually, you should use [services](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-services-and-databases-in-bitbucket-pipelines-874786688.html) instead:

```
definitions:
  services:
    dynamodb-local:
      image: amazon/dynamodb-local
      memory: 2048
  pipelines:
    default:
      - step:
          image: python:3.6
          size: 2x
          services:
            - dynamodb-local
          script:
            - export DYNAMODB_LOCAL_URL=http://localhost:8000
            - export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
            - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=''
            - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=''
            - aws --endpoint-url ${DYNAMODB_LOCAL_URL} dynamodb delete-table --table-name test || true
            - aws --endpoint-url ${DYNAMODB_LOCAL_URL} dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://test.table.json
            - python -m unittest test_module.TestClass
```

You'll probably need to double the size of container and memory as DynamoDB is pretty heavvweight (but it may work on defaults as well).

Comment: As you can see in my docker run command, I need to override the entrypoint of the docker container. Reading the Atlassian docs, I couldn't find a way to do that using the services option.

Comment: @rcdsystems. I see. Most probably, you need that to use `-sharedDb`. It's not possible to do that with services yet, but you can just use predefined `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` (like in my example) and then use the same in you tests. Doing this you'll be accessing the same DB.

Comment: As per their [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.UsageNotes.html): `-sharedDb` — If you specify `-sharedDb`, DynamoDB uses a single database file instead of separate files for each credential and Region. So just use the same credentials and region